# If conditioning on content of a variable (if contain char)

Tags: php, smarty3

To create proper og:description for Facebook I want the first 200 char of the text articles have to be used as description (else it will be the title only).

So in my header I wrote;

```
{if not empty($post_info.parsed_excerpt)}
<meta name="description" content="{$post_info.parsed_excerpt|truncate:200|escape}" property="og:description">
{else}
<meta name="description" content="{$post_info.title|escape} - {$blog_data.title|escape}" property="og:description">
{/if}
```

I though I got it right, but I found exceptions.
Articles may contain more things than just readable text and an image plugin can be there too `<img src="http.../>`. I have even a case where there is no text content but just an image.

So I needed to adapt it.
I found strip_tags modifier so I tweaked a bit 
`{$post_info.parsed_excerpt|truncate:200|escape}`
to
`{$post_info.parsed_excerpt|truncate:200|strip_tags|escape}`
and the description is now without any tags. Half done !:)

Still I need the first condition `{if not empty($post_info.parsed_excerpt)}` to look for `$post_info.parsed_excerpt` without tags and I couldn’t figure how.

Thank for you help

Comment: You better first strip tags and then truncate to 200: `{$post_info.parsed_excerpt|strip_tags|truncate:200|escape}`

Comment: What is the first condition? I don't get it... Just do the same for the other variable...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not versed in smarty3 at all, in fact this is the first I've heard of it. Also I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with your new if statement, are you trying to check if, excluding HTML tags and their attributes, the string is empty? If so could you not strip the tags prior to the conditional, assign that to a new variable and then check that instead e.g. (excuse this being in sort of pseudo code and not smarty, as mentioned I'm unfamiliar with it) `$excerpt_without_tags = strip_tags($post_info.parsed_excerpt);
if (not empty($excerpt_without_tags)) {
// Do stuff
}`

Also, just from the title saying about if contains char, look at the php strpos() function, again not sure about smarty support of that function.

Hope this might help you a bit, and sorry if I misunderstood!

EDIT: formatting